# How to execute command inside vim?

Tags: bash, vim

I want to run shell script inside Vim editor.
I heard it is possible but do not know.

Command:`./shell.sh` inside `vim`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it.  A primary question is "Do you want the output from the script in the file?"

1. If you want the output in the file:

   ```
   :r!./shell.sh
   ```
2. If you don't want the output in the file:

   ```
   :!./shell.sh
   ```
3. If you have the line `./shell.sh` in the file, you can include the output in the file with:

   ```
    !!sh
   ```
4. If you've done it before, you have more options.
5. If you save the command in a named buffer you have still more options.
6. If you want the script to have a portion of the file (edit buffer) as its standard input, you have an enormous number of options you can use in conjunction with either of these mechanisms.

Answer (score 4):

Prefix the command with a `!`. For example, open Vim and write:

```
:!ls
```

This will execute the shell `ls` command.

Note that you'll have to be in the correct directory within Vim for this to work.

Comment: But hey, if you're not in the right directory, just change it with `:cd`, or `:!ls path/to/desired/dest`, etc. You also might want to mention `:r!<command>`, which lets you output the command's output into the current buffer.